Reduce is not giving a correct output
For some reason, the output of the code below is False.
Reduce[(1/(
 2 a (-2 r + c^2 (1 + r)) (-1 + x)) (r - a c (2 + r) - 
   3 a r (-1 + x) + c^2 (-r + a (2 + r) x) - 
   Sqrt[-1 + c] Sqrt[r]
     Sqrt[(-1 + c) (1 + c)^2 r + 
     2 a (r + c (2 - (2 + c) r) + (-1 + c) (1 + c)^2 r x) + 
     a^2 (-8 + 4 c - r + 5 c r + 
        2 (r + c (2 - (2 + c) r)) x + (-1 + c) (1 + 
           c)^2 r x^2)])) > 1 && (c - a (1 - c))/c > r > a/(1 + a - c) && 1 > c > a > 0]

The way I understand the result is that Mathematica suggests that they can not all be true at the same time.
But, for example {c -> .5, a -> .1, r -> .8, x -> .15} will satisfy that.
Am I understanding it wrong? Or, is the Reduce function giving me a wrong output here?

Congratulation, you seem to discover a serious bug. ;-) Should be reported to Wolfram.

Omg! I feel good and bad at the same time. Are bugs like this common? I am not feeling confident about my other results now then!

Bugs appear from time to time like with any other software. It should be investigated what is special about your inequality system. The output of Reduce is reliable most of the time.

OK! Thank you for your reply! (and, reported)

@azerbajdzan This is not a bug, see my answer.

Did you try Reduce[(1/(2 a (-2 r + c^2 (1 + r)) (-1 + x)) (r - a c (2 + r) -         3 a r (-1 + x) + c^2 (-r + a (2 + r) x) -         Sqrt[-1 + c] Sqrt[          r] Sqrt[(-1 + c) (1 + c)^2 r +            2 a (r + c (2 - (2 + c) r) + (-1 + c) (1 + c)^2 r x) +            a^2 (-8 + 4 c - r + 5 c r +               2 (r + c (2 - (2 + c) r)) x + (-1 +                  c) (1 + c)^2 r x^2)])) > 1 && (c - a (1 - c))/c > r >     a/(1 + a - c) && 1 > c > a > 0, Complexes]?

@azerbajdzan ; I think this is not a bug. Up to the documentation if an expression includes inequalities, then by default all variables are assumed real and Reduce works over the reals.  However, there may be complex solutions. To find these, the domain Complexes should be explicitly indicated.

This is not a bug. Your inequality contains Sqrt[-1 + c]. In general, this is a complex number, which you cannot compare unless $c \ge 1$. But this contradicts your other condition $1>c$.

It is not so simple. For example, Reduce[Sqrt[x]*Sqrt[x - 2] < 0, x, Complexes] performs Re[x] < 0 && Im[x] == 0.

Your explanation is not deep and exact. Up to the documentation if an expression includes inequalities, then by default all variables are assumed real and Reduce works over the reals. However, there may be complex-valued solutions. To find these, the domain Complexes should be explicitly indicated.

@yarchik Yes, you are right, the documentation states this limitation of Reduce. But then there is a question how to solve such a system? If the only requirement is that all three inequalities are satisfied after substitution of real variables. The OP values of variables are solution of the system even if Reduce was not designed for solving such cases.

@azerbajdzan Thanks, I feel that this question will be closed (I did not vote for closing). Given that there are already 3 closing votes, it might be better to ask how to solve such a problem as an independent question.

@yarchik Actually the documentation says what to do in such cases :-) Look at my answer. (+1) from me to your answer.

@yarchik's answer is correct that it is not a bug. I assumed it to be a bug too quickly without really looking what expressions contained and what documentation says about possible issues.
But anyway Reduce can in general solve even such systems but we need to add that variables are real and we are solving over Complexes.
The same is with FindInstance.
This returns {} because no solutions could be found.
FindInstance[(1/(2 a (-2 r + c^2 (1 + r)) (-1 + x)) (r - 
       a c (2 + r) - 3 a r (-1 + x) + c^2 (-r + a (2 + r) x) - 
       Sqrt[-1 + c] Sqrt[
         r] Sqrt[(-1 + c) (1 + c)^2 r + 
          2 a (r + c (2 - (2 + c) r) + (-1 + c) (1 + c)^2 r x) + 
          a^2 (-8 + 4 c - r + 5 c r + 
             2 (r + c (2 - (2 + c) r)) x + (-1 + 
                c) (1 + c)^2 r x^2)])) > 1 && (c - a (1 - c))/c > r > 
   a/(1 + a - c) && 1 > c > a > 0, {a, c, r, x}]


{}

But if we add ...&& {a, c, r, x} \[Element] Reals, {a, c, r, x}, Complexes] a solution is found.
FindInstance[(1/(2 a (-2 r + c^2 (1 + r)) (-1 + x)) (r - 
       a c (2 + r) - 3 a r (-1 + x) + c^2 (-r + a (2 + r) x) - 
       Sqrt[-1 + c] Sqrt[
         r] Sqrt[(-1 + c) (1 + c)^2 r + 
          2 a (r + c (2 - (2 + c) r) + (-1 + c) (1 + c)^2 r x) + 
          a^2 (-8 + 4 c - r + 5 c r + 
             2 (r + c (2 - (2 + c) r)) x + (-1 + 
                c) (1 + c)^2 r x^2)])) > 1 && (c - a (1 - c))/c > r > 
   a/(1 + a - c) && 
  1 > c > a > 0 && {a, c, r, x} \[Element] Reals, {a, c, r, 
  x}, Complexes]


{{a -> 1/15, c -> 1/15 (1 + Sqrt[31]), r -> 46/125, x -> -17}}

So same should be possible with Reduce. (it took some time as the system is complicated but solution was found).
Reduce[(1/(2 a (-2 r + c^2 (1 + r)) (-1 + x)) (r - a c (2 + r) - 
       3 a r (-1 + x) + c^2 (-r + a (2 + r) x) - 
       Sqrt[-1 + c] Sqrt[
         r] Sqrt[(-1 + c) (1 + c)^2 r + 
          2 a (r + c (2 - (2 + c) r) + (-1 + c) (1 + c)^2 r x) + 
          a^2 (-8 + 4 c - r + 5 c r + 
             2 (r + c (2 - (2 + c) r)) x + (-1 + 
                c) (1 + c)^2 r x^2)])) > 1 && (c - a (1 - c))/c > r > 
   a/(1 + a - c) && 
  1 > c > a > 0 && {a, c, r, x} \[Element] Reals, {a, c, r, 
  x}, Complexes]


(0 < a < 1/
    4 && ((a < c <= a + Sqrt[2 a + a^2] && 
       a/(1 + a - c) < r < (-a + c + a c)/
        c && (-a + a c - c r + a c r)/(a c r) < x < 
        1) || (a + Sqrt[2 a + a^2] < c < 
        1 && ((a/(1 + a - c) < 
            r < -(c^2/(-2 + c^2)) && ((-a + a c - c r + a c r)/(
              a c r) < 
              x <= (-2 a c + r - a r + c r + 2 a c r - c^2 r + 
                a c^2 r - c^3 r)/(a (-1 + c) (1 + c)^2 r) - 
               2 Sqrt[-((-c^2 + 2 r - c^2 r + c^4 r - 2 c^2 r^2 + 
                  c^4 r^2)/((-1 + c)^2 (1 + c)^4 r^2))] || 
             x > 1)) || (-(c^2/(-2 + c^2)) < r < (-a + c + a c)/
            c && (-a + a c - c r + a c r)/(a c r) < x < 1))))) || (1/
    4 <= a < 1 && a < c < 1 && 
   a/(1 + a - c) < r < (-a + c + a c)/c && (-a + a c - c r + a c r)/(
    a c r) < x < 1)


Very informative! (+)

+1 for && {a, c, r, x} \[Element] Reals.
